# How to print InternalIP of nodes using jq in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, jq

I want to print the internal IP of all nodes in the same line separated by a space using `jq` in k8s. How can I do this?

Using jsonpath I can filter using `.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIP")]`. How to achieve the same with `jq`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use select and pipe to achieve desired output.

below command shows the internal ip separated by new-line

```
kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[].status.addresses[] | select(.type=="InternalIP") | .address'
```

for space separated internal-ips:

```
kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[].status.addresses[] | select(.type=="InternalIP") | .address' | tr -d '\"' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: There is a typo on `kubeclt`. Also, the OP is asking the output to be "in the same line separated by a space".

Comment: Thanks @AbuHanifa. This is exactly what I was looking for.  Also, for getting the output in the same line we can use -j flag of jq.  jq -jr 'items[].status.addresses[] | select(.type=="InternalIP") | .address+" "+'

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using the following command

```
 kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIP")].address}'
```

Checkout [kubectl Cheat sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) for more examples